# gradle project sync failed . android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

i'm new to android and i have a problem with this in the picture :

[image]

i tired to update constraint layout and constraint layout solver but each time i try to update in sdk manager update finish successfully but when i look at sdk manager again it's unchecked . for example after downloading constraint layout and constraint layout solver successfully :
[image]

but when i look at the android sdk path in the finder there is 4 version of constraint Layout installed : 
1.0.0alpha7
1.0.0alpha2
1.0.1
1.0.2

i downloaded gradle 2.14 and copy and replace unzipped file with the default gradle 3.3 installed by android studio but ... no change !

can anyone plz help . i spend 5 hours on this and nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the error message, the problem is with the `AppCompat` support library, not the ConstraintLayout library. Specify a particular version or add an `*` after the major version code, like so:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

or

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.*'`

Comment: i changed that line to :
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

and it works . thank you .

Comment: Awesome, thanks for letting me know! I'm glad it worked. Please accept my answer using the green checkmark if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Click on this text:

[image]

and then press **Right Alt + Enter** (shortcut for quick fixes) -> Select the first suggestion which should state something like *Change version to...25.x.x*.

This will ensure that you will be using the newest version.