# Android Studio 2.2 and 2.3 errors

Tags: android-studio-2.3

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbgN3.jpg)

I am a new Android Studio user, and I have this error that I am yet to resolve:

> Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2

I have updated Android Studio and support repositories and also reinstalled it entirely, but still does not know what the problem is.

I have attached the screenshot of the issue. Please, how can I get Android Studio fully functional again?

Comment: [CLICK ON HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43238643/7820465) Check this link, this may help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved it.
There was a hint from the build file (app) stating there is a more recent version for 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2' and the newer version is 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'.
I changed 25.0.2 to 25.3.1 in the build script manually and synced. This will cause Android Studio to request a download of the new support repository. When this completes, it will resolve the Gradle build issue and also any issue with inability to resolve 'appCompatActivity' in the .java file.